# What's the use of universal characters on POSIX system?

Tags: c, unix, unicode

In C one can pass unicode characters to printf() like this:

```
printf("some unicode char: %c\n", "\u00B1");
```

But the problem is that on POSIX compliant systems `char' is always 8 bits and most of UTF-8 character such as the above are wider and don't fit into char and as the result nothing is printed on the terminal. I can do this to achieve this effect however:

```
printf("some unicode char: %s\n", "\u00B1");
```

%s placeholder is expanded automatically and a unicode character is printed on the terminal. Also, in a standard it says:

> If the hexadecimal value for a universal character name is less than
>   0x20 or in the range 0x7F-0x9F (inclusive), or if the universal
>   character name designates a character in the basic source character
>   set, then the program is illformed.

When I do this:

```
printf("letter a: %c\n", "\u0061");
```

gcc says:

> error: \u0061 is not a valid universal character

So this technique is also unusable for printing ASCII characters. In this article on Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_(computing)#cite_ref-3 it says:

> A char in the C programming language is a data type with the size of
>   exactly one byte, which in turn is defined to be large enough to
>   contain any member of the basic execution character set and UTF-8 code
>   units.

But is this doable on POSIX systems?

Comment: One good reason for `printf("%c","…")` not to work is that `%c` tells printf to expect a char and "…" has type `char*` regardless of what it contains. That makes it difficult to understand what you are asking. It could not work in any case.

Comment: `printf("some unicode char: %c\n", "\u00B1");` With %c shoudn't '\u00B1' be used, instead of "\u00B" ?

Comment: @ Pascal Cuoq: Oh yes, I didn't know that. But according to the Wikipedia article one can print a unicode character in a single char. How to do this with Unicode escape sequences? And why this works: printf("unicode char: %c\n", "±");

Comment: When I do this program compiles but gcc shows "multi-character character constant" warning and prints only a question mark in the terminal. I also thought it should print a unicode single character but it doesn't :(

Comment: I think I got it. In order to print '±' I need to write printf("some unicode char: %c%c\n", 0xc2, 0xb1);. But what worries me is that here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.std.c/aPENvL9wZFw they say that things like 'char  c1 = '\U12345678';' are perfectly legal.

Comment: `printf("some unicode char: %c\n", "\u00B1");` shouldn't work. You are printing a string (`char *`) as if it were a `char`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use of universal characters in byte-based strings is dependent on the compile-time and run-time character encodings matching, so it's generally not a good idea except in certain situations. However they work very well in wide string and wide character literals: `printf("%ls", L"\u00B1");` or `printf("%lc", L'\00B1');` will print U+00B1 in the correct encoding for your locale.